# Arkham City 'full screen on' does not fill the screen

Tags: batman-arkham-city, graphics-card

Running Radeon HD6800, Win7 64-bit Home Premium - cannot get rid of black border around the game on fullscreen.

Arkham Asylum did not have this problem.  DX9 and DX11 both have the problem. Resolution changes make no difference.

Also, the benchmark process hangs when it gets to 'Hit Esc to finish' (not a blocking issue).

AMD software is at Catalyst 12.3 - 12.4 upgrade appears to work but when you check for updates again, it downloads repeatedly.

Comment: What resolution are you playing at?

Comment: And what resolution is your display?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to adjust the resolution of the game to fit your screen perfectly.

I can't suggest which would be best as I do not know what type of screen you have, what your current resolution is, etc.

What I can suggest, however, is going through each resolution setting/option and applying it to see which fits the best.

Comment: Thanks, I fiddled with it and DX9 plus 1680/1050 works best.  Not sure why this is so much harder than AA to set up.